# WooComerce, if custom checkbox is checked hide stock status

Tags: php, checkbox, woocommerce

I have a bit trouble with woocomerce checkbox, i add custom checkbox to product page wit this code:

```
 woocommerce_wp_checkbox( 
array( 
    'id'            => '_checkbox', 
    'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple', 
    'label'         => __('My Checkbox Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'description'   => __( 'Check me!', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
);
}
```

then save value with this:

```
    $woocommerce_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkbox', $woocommerce_checkbox );
```

Now i tried to write function which make my stock status hiden when this checkbox is checked but i fail , can i ask you guys for some support ?

Comment: anything you have tried ?

Comment: Well i tried to put some basic if () statment in woocomerce single-product.php but its looks like this is not good way. Im quite new in php and Woo so im stuck .

Comment: If you are using the code as shown in your post then it won't work, code will create a text area field not a checkbox.

Comment: Ah i pasate not this function  :) , i'll corect in in a moment . It works, i strugle only with make this if else statement to this  :(

Comment: What's the variable associated with the checkbox when used in your loop/in the template? And what condition did you try for the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code for saving the option of checkbox works fine and the saved option for that products reflects in the database then adding the following code will help to to complete your task

```
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_html','wdm_remove_stock_html',10,3);

function wdm_remove_stock_html($availability_html, $availability, $product)
{
if ( 'yes' === get_post_meta( $product->id,'_checkbox', true) ) {
    return '';
}else{
 return $availability_html;   
}
}
```

Comment: Yes , that works perfect :) Im beginner in Woo , thank you for help . !